# Java Library for Sound Manipulation

Tags: java, audio, pitch

I have a .pcm file with a sound that I would like to add different effects to. What I am looking for is a simple way (prefeably a library) that can help me with these effects.

My top priority is to change the pitch of the audio.

I would like a function that takes a byte array (or float), and changes the pitch of the audio in that array.

Answer (score 2):

Java has an API for dealing with [WAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) and [MIDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_Instrument_Digital_Interface) files, it's included in the JDK by default.

[This](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/sound/index.html) is the documentation for the java sound API.

Comment: I don't think the java sound API is able to change the pitch. Or am I wrong on this point?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the API,but that's the closest the JDK can offer,you mgight want to check OpenAL or other third-party APIs